# What does the notation of $1\{a_i=b\}$ mean in a summation?

Tags: summation, notation

As seen in:

http://stanford.edu/~cpiech/cs221/img/kmeansMath.png

Does it mean sum for all elements that satisfy the condition? What does the 1 mean? Is there a name for this notation?

Comment: Seems like the indicator function. It is 1 if $c^{(i)}=j$, 0 otherwise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function